# Correct case for each reserved word in SQL Server?

Tags: sql-server, best-practices, collation, metadata

Is the most correct spelling for `int` upper case `INT` or lower case `int`?

There are many other `reserved words` in SQL Server.

How to find out the best case for each word?

For example the picture below is a random piece of code, with many different words in it, how can I verify that those words have the, so to say, 'right' case spelling?

Would these things matter in case I have a CS (case sensitive) database?
Would any interfere in the performance?

Let's say `select 1 from table1 where 1=1` and `SELECT 1 FROM table1 WHERE 1=1`?

[image]

[How to Convert Data to Proper Case In SQL Server](https://dba.stackexchange.com/questions/165762/how-to-convert-data-to-proper-case-in-sql-server)

Answer (score 5, accepted):

So,

Writing it as an answer for anyone else who might need this in the future-the answer to this question is described very nicely in the [Why I use lower case for data type names (now)](https://blogs.sentryone.com/aaronbertrand/backtobasics-lower-case-data-types/) blog post from Aaron Bertrand.

As he explains in his blog post, this is important when using different database collations from the default one, for example (from the blog):

Considering this database:

```
CREATE DATABASE floobmort COLLATE Latin1_General_BIN2; 
GO
USE floobmort;
```

The following query will provide an empty result set because "That comparison tries to compare `N'INT'` to what's stored in the table, `N'int'`, and because the comparison is done using a binary collation, it returns false."

```
SELECT system_type_id 
FROM sys.types 
WHERE [name] IN (N'INT', N'VARCHAR');
```